# What is the preferred convention for Perl Inheritance

Tags: perl, inheritance, syntax

In the example below, I have 3 different syntax/mechanisms for defining inheritance. All of them work. Can someone tell me which one is preferred and why (yes, I know "there is more than ..."). Also, why do I need "use WB" in 1 case and not the other 2. TIA

The main -

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
#######################

use strict;
use River;
use Ocean;
use Lake;

my $pName = $0;         $pName =~ s/.*\///;     $pName =~ s/\.\w+$//;

my @sources = (Ocean->new ('Pacific', 1),
               River->new ('Brazos', 0),
               Lake->new ('Tahoe', 0) );
foreach (@sources) {
        $_->printIfSaline ($pName);
}
```

The modules (Lake, River and Ocean inherit from WaterBody):

```
######################
# File: Lake.pm
######################

package Lake;

use strict;
use WaterBody;
our @ISA = ('WaterBody');

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    $class->SUPER::new(@_)
}

sub printIfSaline {
        my ($self, $prompt) = @_;
        my $name = $self->getName();
        my $taste = $self->isSaline() ? "salty" : "sweet";
        print "$prompt: Lake $name has $taste water\n";
}

1

######################
# File: Ocean.pm
######################

package Ocean;

use strict;
use parent 'WaterBody';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    $class->SUPER::new(@_);
}

sub printIfSaline {
        my ($self, $prompt) = @_;
        my $name = $self->getName;
        my $taste = $self->SUPER::isSaline() ? "salty" : "sweet";
        print "$prompt: $name Ocean has $taste water\n";
}

1

######################
# File: River.pm
######################

package River;

use strict;
use base 'WaterBody';

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    $class->SUPER::new(@_);
}

sub printIfSaline {
    my ($self, $prompt) = @_;
    my $name = $self->getName;
    my $taste = $self->isSaline ? "salty" : "sweet";
    print "$prompt: $name river has $taste water\n";
}

1

######################
# File: WaterBody.pm
######################

package WaterBody;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{name} = shift;
    $self->{saline} = shift;
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub getName {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->{name}
}

sub isSaline {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->{saline}
}

1
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `use parent` pragma sets up the `@ISA` at compile time.  From [parent](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html)

> Establish an ISA relationship with base classes at compile time

When you `use ParentClass;` and then manually set up `@ISA` that happens at run time.  In this case code in `BEGIN`, `CHECK`, or `INIT` blocks won't be able to use the inheritance hierarchy without extra work.

The `use base` pragma is older and `parent` is recommended in docs.  From [base](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html)

> Unless you are using the fields pragma, consider this module discouraged in favor of the lighter-weight parent

Thus I'd say go with `use parent`.

Answer (score 8):

Manipulating @ISA is the oldest way. [base](http://p3rl.org/base) was the second way, and [parent](http://p3rl.org/parent) is even newer. So, I'd recommend `parent` for new projects.

Answer (score 8):

```
use parent 'Foo::Bar';
```

is cleanest, although the repetitious

```
use Foo::Bar qw( );
our @ISA = 'Foo::Bar';
```

is still commonly used. The former also has the advantage of happening sooner (when the file is compiled) than the latter (when the file is executed), though that rarely matters.

*base* is discouraged because it silences errors that occur when a module is loaded.